# Proper use of Application.Run

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am not sure I fully understand the use of Application.Run. I have tried using this in one of my macros, but I did not see the expected change. Here is the setup. I have an Excel Add-In that runs several macros from a menu system. One of the macros will copy data from an extract workbook to a master workbook. The other day, one of the users had applied a filter to one of the columns and did not clear it before running the copy code. This caused the data to not copy correctly. So I have researched how to run a code on the master workbook from the extract workbook to clear the filter before copy/paste occurs.

To better clarify how I need this to work:

1. **Workbook A** contains data that needs to move to **Workbook B**
2. **Workbook A** will sort the data and remove data that is not needed in
   **workbook B**.
3. In **Workbook B** I have code that will show all data if a filter is
   applied upon open and close of the workbook.
4. Before copying and pasting the data from **workbook A** to **workbook B**, I
   need to have **workbook A** trigger the unfilter code in **workbook B** to perform the sub in **workbook B**.

This is the code from the extract workbook (**workbook A**) (that uses the Add-In):

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1601_January()

Dim ANS As Long

ANS = MsgBox("Is the January 2016 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
If ANS = vbNo Or IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - January 2016") = False Then
    MsgBox "The required workbook is not currently open. This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "1" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR

Application.Run "'Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm'!Unfilter"

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:AE2000")
    .Apply
End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    'With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
        'erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        '.Range("A2:AE" & erow).AutoFilter 'leaving arguments blank clears all filters, but leaves the drop-down arrows (filter mode still on)
    'End With

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, this will copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 31)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, this will paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is the Unfilter code that I need to run on the Master workbook (**Workbook B**)(this is located in a module in the Master workbook):

```
Sub Unfilter()

    Dim she As Variant
    For Each she In Worksheets
         If she.FilterMode Then she.ShowAllData
    Next
End Sub
```

Am I using the Application.Run correctly? Or is there another issue with my code? I do not get any errors. When I tested this, the data in **workbook B** remained filtered.

Comment: Is `UnFilter` in a module? Or is it in a `Worksheet_Module`? If it's in a module, what happens if you use `she.AutoFilterMode = False` vs. `she.ShowAllData`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I just tested that and had the same result. It is worth noting that I have the same Unfilter code in the Workbook_Open and Workbook_BeforeClose  and it works as intended. I used that code and put it in it's own sub to use with the Application.Run, but I get nothing.

Comment: Did you step through the code line-by-line? If so, when it moves to the `Run` does it take to that code so that it's actually running?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think that is my dilemma. I do not know how to call the macro from within code that is running on the extract file to perform the unfilter on the Master workbook before the extract code performs the copy/paste into the Master workbook. Does this order of events make sense?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman No, I did not step through the code.

Comment: Step through the code `Extract_Sort_1601_January` line-by-line and see what happens when it hits the `Run` command. If it is working correctly, you will see the debugger move to that code and process it line-by-line. If something else happens, you have information on what needs fixing :)

Comment: Ran through it step by step and found a misspelled word. Corrected that and ran it again. The use of she.AutoFilterMode = False removed the arrows on all the headers. Not a desired result.

Comment: does `ShowAllData` work now? (with the misspelled word fix)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ha ha. I actually misspelled AutoFilterMode (I had AutiFilterMode). So, a direct answer is no.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I apologize, I did not answer one of your questions from above, the Unfilter sub is in a regular module.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Please review my edited question. I think that I may not have been specific enough of my intended goal. I am doing more research and have come to believe that Application.Run is basically doing a Call of a macro that resides in an external workbook and run the code on the "calling" workbook.

Comment: good find. surprised I didn't this before. In the `Unfitler` sub change `For Each she In Worksheets` to `For Each she In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` to have it run on the workbook containing the code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I was just able to test it and it works perfectly. Thanks for all the help again Scott! Put this as an answer and I will definitely accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Unfilter` sub to work directly with the Workbook where the code resides.

See below:

```
Sub Unfilter()

    Dim she As Variant
    For Each she In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         If she.FilterMode Then she.ShowAllData
    Next
End Sub
```